# UnityVS (Visual Studio Tools for Unity 1.9) + Visual Studio Ultimate 2013 Compatibility Issue?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, unity-game-engine, unityvs

I have installed the recently released Visual Studio Tools for Unity 1.9 on my computer with a copy of Visual Studio Ultimate 2013 and am encountering a problem which I can't seem to fix. After creating a new Unity project, importing the VSTU package, and creating a script and opening it, I see a message within the VS 2013 Solution Explorer stating that:

"This project is incompatible with this version of Visual Studio"

However, I have read on the UnityVS site and nothing indicates that it is incompatible with VS 2013. Are there any possible solutions to this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Did you get the 2013 version of the UnityVS?

Comment: I can confirm that it works with 2013 Pro so I don't imagine there should be any issues with 2013 Ultimate.

Comment: Yes, using the 2013 version of UnityVS and 2013 Visual Studio. Does anyone Ultimate to confirm?

Comment: I'm using VS2013 Premium and it works just fine. Did you try to open the VS project with "Menu / Visual Studio Tools / Open in Visual Studio"? What version of Unity do you use?

Comment: Of course VS Ultimate is supported. It seems that the installation failed to recreate the Visual Studio extension cache. We saw this happen if there was a stray devenv.exe process. 

Try to do this: 
- Make sure that you do not have any Visual Studio instance running 
- Properly remove VSTU 2013, using Control Panel, Programs and Features 
- Reinstall VSTU 2013 

If you still encounter issues, repair your Visual Studio Installation using Control Panel, Programs and Features: Microsoft Visual Studio 2013, Modify, Repair. Then if you haven't yet upgraded to Update 3, you should try to.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question now, but I ran into the same problem recently with a brand new install of Unity 4.6.1, VS Professional 2013 and VSTU 2013.

A re-install of VSTU fixed the problem.

Comment: ..and the same problem again with Unity 5.2.2 and VS 2015 Community.  A complete uninstall and reinstall of VSTU fixed it.  (N.B.: "Repair" did not help)